# How to create table in xlst

Tags: xslt

I have table

```
   Symbol             YEAR      Period
______1_________|_____2011____|____1____|
______2_________|_____2011____|____2____|
______3_________|_____2012____|____1____|
______4_________|_____2012____|____2____|
______1_________|_____2013____|____1____|
______2_________|_____2013____|____2____|
______3_________|_____2014____|____1____|
______4_________|_____2014____|____2____|
     ...          ...         ...
     ...          ...         ...
     ...          ...         ...
______1_________|_____2017____|____1____|
______2_________|_____2017____|____2____|
______3_________|_____2018____|____1____|
______4_________|_____2018____|____2____|
```

Field "Symbol" are in xml document. I should to identify Year and period from Symbol field. This year (2011) symbols 1,2 describe the current year, the next year(2012)symbols 1,2 will describe 2013 years and etc.. by analogy with 3,4 symbols describes 2012, 2014, 2016, 2018 ...

Should I create matrix table, for example like date.add.template or maybe can I calculate it, without template?

Best regards

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please, provide reduce  input sample and an explicit desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create table like this [http://www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp)

More informaiton can be found [here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N7450.html)